# See When Someone Was Last Active MS Teams

Tags: microsoft-teams

How can I see when someone was last online in MS Teams ?

Like with Skype is shows when some one was last active or online, I want to be able to use this feature in Teams.

Often people don't sign out of teams, and just leave them selves as away, making it difficult to see whether they are just away, or not even at work.

I've done a bit of googling and couldn't really find anything, some forums seem to say it doesn't exist while others say it does (without showing me where)

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/G1eKj.png …?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the status of the contact is set as is Away, hover the mouse on the contact, it will show the last seen time.

[image]

Comment: knew it would be somewhere simple !

Comment: @PeterH Actually it wasn't. If you see the edits on the answer, I also thought it was not possible. Then went to Teams by pure coincidence hovered on a contact then saw it.